# Django - "missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' " error, while uploading Image

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm very close to making a fully working blog by uploading a Image with a post. But I hit a wall and can't move forward because I can't properly get the view and models to work properly to upload the Image.

The error I'm getting.

```
TypeError at /new/
save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/new/
Django Version: 1.9.8
```

My model class.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    text = models.TextField()
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null = True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Form.

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title' ,'text','docfile',)
```

View.

```
def new_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = PostForm.save(commit = False)
            post.docfile = request.FILES["docfile"]
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk = post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'core/post_edit.html', {'form' : form})
```

HTML Template

```
{% extends 'core/main.html' %}
{% block content %}

<h1>New Post</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

I'm so close, but I just can't figure out where i'm wrong.
Help.

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the error mentioned on the previous answer, you don't have to set the `docfile` attribute manually in the view, the form will save the file automatically to the location specified by the `upload_to` argument (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to).

And if you wanted to set the file manually, this would be the correct way (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.save):

```
post.docfile.save(name, request.FILES["docfile"], save=False)
```

Omitting the save argument if you want to save it straight away.

Comment: Since I already declared a name for the image in my model, how do I pass that name argument to save() function or pass the default name?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
def new_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = PostForm.save(commit = False)
```

do

```
def new_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
```

The problems is that you create new instance of PostForm class. Instead, use already created one.